# Create a Partially Sorted Array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am working my way through Sedgewick and Wayne's *Algorithms, 4th Edition.* (This is not homework.)

One of the exercises (2.1.37) is to write a client that generates partially sorted arrays with all entries within 10 positions of their final place in the array.

My progress is as follows:

If we want to place the numbers 0 through N in an array `[a[0], a[1], ... a[N]],` then we start by placing 0 in a random index from 0 to 10, inclusive. Then, we place 1 in a random unoccupied index from 0 to 11, etc., 11 in an unoccupied index from 1 to 21, etc. It's pretty clear that up through N-10, all entries will have at least one unoccupied position they can belong in. However, I can't see whether this would work for the last 10 entries, since all of their available locations could hypothetically have been filled up by previous numbers.

Is my reasoning correct? Does my algorithm work, and I just can't prove it, or does it fail? If it fails, what's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You're right - it may not work.

There's several ways to approach this problem, but the first thing I would try is to modify [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), e.g. something like

```java
int[] fuzzyRange(int size, int fuzz, Random rng) {
    int[] arr = IntStream.range(0, size).toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // Normal Fisher-Yates would pick a random index in [i, arr.length) for
        // swapping. This instead picks a random index in [i, i+fuzz] where both
        // swapped elements stay within fuzz of their starting indices.
        int j = i, n = 1;
        for (int k = i + 1; k < arr.length && k < i + fuzz; k++) {
                if (k - fuzz <= arr[i] && arr[i] <= k + fuzz &&
                    i - fuzz <= arr[k] && arr[k] <= i + fuzz &&
                    rng.nextInt(++n) == 0) {
                    j = k;
                }
        }
        if (i != j) {
            int tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

(untested). I'm not sure if this generates all legal derangements with equal probability, though.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind `rng.nextInt(++n) == 0`? Are you weighting towards shorter swaps?

Comment: @Dukeling Very simple use of [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). Instead of generating a list of all the legal swap indices, and then choosing a random one, I'm just going through the options one by one, replacing the chosen index with probability 1/n when adding the nth choice. All options have an equal probability of being chosen in the end.